# How to upload file to server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to upload image to server but always getting error from server.

> **Headers.**
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---BOUNDARY
>
> **Body**
>
> -----BOUNDARY
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="pic.jpg"
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
>   HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
>   MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAABAAEDASIA
>   AhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEB
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AL+AD//Z
>   -----BOUNDARY

**I have using below code**

```
-(NSString *)uploadFileToServer:(NSString *)fileName fileData:(NSData *)file1Data
{
NSString *urlString =url.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---BOUNDARY";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"file",@"pic.jpg"];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n–%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:header] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1Data]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n–%@–\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
return returnString;
}
```

**Response**

```
"details": {

    "errors": {

      "file": "is required"
    }
  },
  "error": "Invalid files",

  "error_code": 4,

  "exc_class": "FAPIValidationError",

  "rc": false
```

Comment: if you know about afnetworking then please go with this to upload file

Comment: Actually I have a code is swift2.3

Comment: thanks for your response, can you let me know please which part of code is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried these all links: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=image+upload+to+server+in+ios

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using alamofire?

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
// put your data to multipart here                        
}, to: url) { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

    upload.responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json):
        break:    
        case .failure(_):
        break:    
        }
    }
    case .failure(_):
    break:
    }
}
```